# selecting a value which is subtraction of two summary

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have this query which works...

```
select 
    t.date, 
    sum(gk.d) as d, 
    sum(gk.p) as p,
    (sum(d)-sum(p)) as s
```

But I'm wondering is there a way to select value 's' as d-p, something like this:

```
select 
    t.date, 
    sum(gk.d) as d, 
    sum(gk.p) as p,
    (d-p) as s // not working
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL in general does not support referencing column aliases in the same SELECT clause, which is why the first version works for you but the second does not.  The alternative is to use a derived table/inline view:

```
SELECT x.date,
       x.d,
       x.p,
       x.d - x.p AS s
  FROM (SELECT t.date,
               SUM(gk.d) AS d,
               SUM(gk.p) AS p,
          FROM t
          JOIN gk ON ...) AS x
```

Mind that SQL Server requires you to define a table alias for derive tables/inline views - hence the "AS x"

Answer (score 3):

Take a look on [SELECT doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx), section "Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement"; they have an explanation why and where you can refer columns by aliases. 
The common workaround is to use derived tables or CTEs.
So it should work for you:

```
SELECT d, p , d-p AS s 
FROM 
(
   select 
   t.date, 
   sum(gk.d) as d, 
   sum(gk.p) as p
   FROM ....
)a
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Common Table Expression in SQL 2008:

```
WITH sumCTE AS
(
   SELECT t.date
      , SUM(gk.d) as d 
      , SUM(gk.p) as p
   FROM ...
)
SELECT d, p, d - p AS s
FROM sumCTE
```

Comment: The `WITH` syntax is syntactic sugar for derived table/inline view.  There's no performance benefit to it in this example, and is 2005+ (besides limited support elsewhere - MySQL has yet to support the WITH clause).